# Show does not combine/display multiple graphics?

Tags: graphics

```
jerry = {
    Graphics[Line[{ {11,7} , {9,6} , {8,6} , {7.5,6.5} , {8,12} , {9,12} , {9.5,11.5} , {10,12} , {10.5,12} , {11,11} , {11,7} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {9,13} , {8.5,13} , {7.5,14} , {8,14} , {9,13.5} , {9,13} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {8.5,13} , {7.5,13} , {6.5,14.5} , {7,14.5} , {8.5,13} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {9,13} , {9.5,14.5} , {9,14.5} , {9,13} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {9,15} , {9,15.5} , {8.5,15.5} , {8.5,15} , {9,15} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {9.5,14.5} , {9.5,15.5} , {8,15.5} , {8,15} , {7,15.5} , {7,15} , {8,14.5} , {9.5,14.5} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {9,16} , {9,16.5} , {8.5,16.5} , {8.5,16} , {9,16} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {9,16.5} , {9,16.5} , {8.5,17.5} , {8.5,16.5} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {8,16} , {8,16.5} , {7.5,16.5} , {7.5,16} , {8,16} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {8,16.5} , {8,17.5} , {7.5,17.5} , {7.5,16.5} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {9,13} , {6,13} , {5,13.5} , {3.5,16.5} , {3.5,17} , {4,17} , {4,18} , {2,19} , {5,18.5} , {6,19} , {6.5,20} , {6.5,19} , {8,19.5} , {7,19} , {7.5,19} , {9,18} , {9.5,16} , {10,16} , {10,15.5} , {9,13} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {4,15.5} , {3,15} , {2,15} , {1,16} , {1,18} , {2,19} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {7.5,19} , {7.5,21} , {7,21} , {6,20} , {6,19} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {9,13} , {14.5,17.5} , {14,18} , {14.5,18.5} , {15,18} , {15.5,18.5} , {16,18.5} , {16.5,18} , {16.5,17.5} , {16,17} , {15,16.5} , {10.5,12} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {6,13} , {5,12.5} , {2.5,9} , {2,9} , {2,8} , {3,8} , {3,8.5} , {6,11} , {6.5,10} , {5.5,2} , {4.5,1.5} , {4.5,1} , {5,.5} , {5.5,.5} , {7.5,5} , {8.5,5.5} , {8.5,2.5} , {9.5,2} , {10.5,2.5} , {9.5,3} , {9.5,4} , {11,7} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {6.5,17.5} , {6.5,18} , {7,18} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {9,15} , {12,16} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {9,15.5} , {12,17} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {8,15} , {4,14} }]],
    Graphics[Line[{ {8,14.5} , {4,13}}]]
};




blankDo[name_,xmin_,xmax_,ymin_,ymax_] := blank[name] = 
Graphics[
    GridLines -> {Range[xmin,xmax], Range[ymin,ymax]}, 
    GridLinesStyle -> {{Opacity[1/2], LightGray, Dashed}, {Opacity[1/2], LightGray, Dashed}}, 
    PlotRange -> {{xmin-0.2,xmax+0.2}, {ymin-0.2,ymax+0.2}}, 
    AxesStyle -> {{LightGray, Dashed}, {LightGray, Dashed}}, 
    Frame -> True,
    FrameTicks -> {Range[xmin,xmax], Range[ymin,ymax]}, 
    ImageSize -> Full
];
blankDo["jerry",0,17,0,22];
blankDo["cartoon_character_A",0,17,0,22];
blankDo["cartoon_character_B",0,17,0,22];
blankDo["cartoon_character_C",0,17,0,22];
blankDo["cartoon_character_D",0,17,0,22];


Show[jerry, blank["jerry"]]
```

Does not get a combined graph, while `Show[blank["jerry"]]` and `Show[jerry]` works fine seperately.

I am using multiple `Graphics[Line[{}]]` so that I can check each segments later. `blankDo` creates each blank template for drawing and I am hoping `Show[jerry, blank["jerry"]]` will show both the picture and the template.

What's the `shortest` way to fix it? (keeping most of the structure of these codes)

Comment: Does changing `Graphics[GridLines -> .., ..]` to `Graphics[{}, GridLines->.., ..]` help?

Comment: First change:  You need only one call to `Line` (put all line segments within a single call).

Comment: One thing to remember is that `Show` takes options from the first graphics object, which means that you have to write `Show[blank["jerry"], jerry]` and not `Show[jerry, blank["jerry"]]`. Otherwise the option values for the grid lines etc. will be the default values. Also, you need to make the change Carl recommended. With those two changes it will work.

Comment: @C.E. Worked like a magic! All sorted.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu since that was the issue I marked it as a duplicate of a generic topic for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments,

```
blankDo[name_,xmin_,xmax_,ymin_,ymax_] := blank[name] = 
Graphics[{},
    GridLines -> {Range[xmin,xmax], Range[ymin,ymax]}, 
    GridLinesStyle -> {{Opacity[1/2], LightGray, Dashed}, {Opacity[1/2], LightGray, Dashed}}, 
    PlotRange -> {{xmin-0.2,xmax+0.2}, {ymin-0.2,ymax+0.2}}, 
    AxesStyle -> {{LightGray, Dashed}, {LightGray, Dashed}}, 
    Frame -> True,
    FrameTicks -> {Range[xmin,xmax], Range[ymin,ymax]}, 
    ImageSize -> Full
];
```

together with

```
Show[blank["jerry"], jerry]
```

worked perfectly!